# I want to use group by and summarize in R, but keep some values from the observation

Tags: r

so I have been trying to figure out which party won in a specific region in my country using the number of votes per location, the problem is that when I use group by region (DEPARTAMENTO), I cannot keep the name of the party, only the votes.
When I group by region and party (DEPARTAMENTO, AGRUPACION), instead of 25 values I got 68 values because of the different denominations for political parties.

I hope this is not that confusing. And thanks.

```
ERM2002ganador <-
ERMfinalt2002 %>%
group_by(DEPARTAMENTO)%>%
summarize(max(VTOTAL,na.rm = FALSE))
```

I am trying to get something like the following

```
DEPARTAMENTO VOTES(VTOTAL) AGRUPACION   TYPE
LAMBAYEQUE   250000        PERU POSIBLE PP
```

What I got now is only

```
DEPARTAMENTO VOTES
Lambayeque   250000
```

And If I use the group by for TYPE too I got the following

```
DEPARTAMENTO VOTES TYPE
LAMBAYEQUE   25000 PP
LAMBAYEQUE   20000 MR
```

Comment: Note there's also aggregate functions like e.g. `first(AGRUPACION)` to pick the first entry per group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::slice_max()` instead of `summarize()`. This will keep the row with the highest `VTOTAL` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

ERMfinalt2002 %>%
  group_by(DEPARTAMENTO) %>%
  slice_max(VTOTAL) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  DEPARTAMENTO AGRUPACION              TYPE  VTOTAL
  <fct>        <fct>                   <fct>  <dbl>
1 AREQUIPA     PERU POSIBLE            PP    227581
2 LAMBAYEQUE   PARTIDO APRISTA PERUANO PP    290516
3 LIMA         PERU POSIBLE            PP    147409
```

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

ERMfinalt2002 <- expand.grid(
    DEPARTAMENTO = c("AREQUIPA", "LAMBAYEQUE", "LIMA"),
    AGRUPACION = c("PERU POSIBLE", "PARTIDO APRISTA PERUANO"),
    TYPE = "PP"
  )

ERMfinalt2002$VTOTAL = round(runif(6, 50000, 300000))
```